# Run JHipster SpringApplication via eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to run the JHipster application via my Eclipse Juno, using jdk 1.7.
The app seems to be loading properly (no console errors), but when i'm trying to reach the server with the client side (or via Postman, by sending a request to the REST servlets in port 8080), it's not responding.

However, when i'm running "mvn spring-boot:run" in the command shell, the server is loaded successfully and is responding to the exact same requests. Also, I managed to run the same command via eclipse with some maven configuration but it seems to be running only the target files (jars) and not the source code. I still haven't been able to run the source code of this app using eclipse in order to properly debug it.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: No surprise that if you run with "mvn" (command line or from Eclipse) you are running from the jars. How are you running in Elcipse? With a main() method, or deployed to a server (note that the URL will be different probably)?

Comment: @Dave Syer, Thanks for your reply. i'm running it with a main() method. there's nothing in the JHipster documentation regarding any server definition for running the app.

Comment: Did you try to use spring boor from inside Eclipse or a server (Tomcat, ...)? I can run the app with spring boot but did not found any working configuration fonr tomcat yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is quite trivial, but since I spent several hours to reach it, it might save some time for others-

1. Download & install STS IDE.
2. Import the project as **existing Maven project**.
3. Run/Debug the project.

I tried to run it via Eclipse the whole time (wasn't familiar with STS to be honest) and this probably needs some extra configuration (another comment with explanations on eclipse configuration will be much appreciated). Once you work with STS, it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need STS, just Eclipse with the J2EE stuff.

I've imported the [sample jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) in Eclipse (without STS) as a Maven project and everything was OK, after installing the maven dependencies.

To run the project, run as an application and search for the Application (com.mycompany.myapp.Application)

Answer (score 0):

This app works for me: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app. It is stuck on Boot RC5 which probably means it's a bit old. Maybe Julien can comment on that (or update it)?